# Cadaver ignoring or not reading/locating the .netrc file for automatic login

Tags: ubuntu, webdav, cadaver

I'm unable to automatically log in to a webdav server using cadaver. I've set up my ~/.netrc file as suggested:

```
machine https://webdav.server.com/
    login me
    password password
```

and changed the permissions using chmod 600 so that 'ls -l ~/.netrc' returns

```
-rw------- 1 root root 78 Aug 10 15:52 /home/local/WIN/me/.netrc
```

Yet when I run cadaver, I'm still prompted for a login:

```
WIN\me@local:/var/www$ sudo cadaver
WARNING: Untrusted server certificate presented for `*.server.com':
Issued to: ... US
Issued by: InCommon, Internet2, Ann Arbor, MI, US
Certificate is valid from Thu, 16 Apr 2015 00:00:00 GMT to Sun, 15 Apr 2018 23:59:59 GMT
Do you wish to accept the certificate? (y/n)
```

And then after typing yes:

```
Authentication required for ESGDAV-LDAP on server `webdav.server.com':
Username:
```

This is on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, with cadaver 0.23.3. I'm able to log in manually without a problem. Is this a permissions issue? Or did I put the .netrc file in the wrong location?

Answer (score 2):

I found this question because I had the same problem.

It worked for me when in ~/.netrc instead of

```
machine http://this.is.url
```

i wrote

```
machine this.is.url
```

Answer (score 0):

In ~/.cadaverrc you can put line

```
open https://webdav.example.com/
```

In ~/.netrc put

```
default
login %login%
password %password%
```